# Cygwin+KiTTYCyg: /bin/sh: No such file or directory

Tags: cygwin, kitty

Trying to use KiTTY with Cygwin (x86) on Windows 7 x64.

1. Installed latest Cygwin and all needed packages.
2. Added `;c:\cygwin\usr\local\bin\;c:\cygwin\bin` to system `Path` env.
3. Downloaded KiTTYCyg for Cygwin 1.7 form here: http://www.9bis.net/kitty/?page=PuTTYCyg and unpacked it to KiTTY dir.
4. When I'm selecting "Cygterm" as connection type in KiTTY and using "-" as command, I'm getting this error in terminal window:

   ```
   /bin/sh: No such file or directory
   ```

   And if using something like "mosh" as command, getting this error:

   ```
   mosh: Permission denied
   ```

Please help me to find a reason.

Answer (score 1):

That message is caused by because the the cygwin1.dll that came with KiTTYCyg is for Cygwin 1.7, but you're probably using a different version.
Delete it. Replace with a copy of the one in c:\cygwin\bin (or add c:\cygwin\bin to your path, etc).

If you're using Cygwin64, you'll need to replace cthelper with cthelper64 as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it's not working for me. I replaced cygwin1.dll and got same errors. When I'm replacing cthelper with cthelper64, I'm getting "failed to run cthelper".

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're running the latest version of KiTTY (0.70.0.1 at the time of this writing), since it adds extra features to detect Cygwin treats (like 64 bits *and* its install path).

What worked for me was to copy `cthelper64.exe` into `C:\cygwin64\bin` and edit `kitty.ini` adding this:

```
[Cygwin integration]
CtHelperPath=C:\cygwin64\bin\cthelper.exe
```

Then in your KiTTY Configuration window you need to add a dash (-) in the Command and select the Cygterm radio:
[KiTTY plus Cygterm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lsFje.png)

Probably you may also want to check that Cyterm branch in the setup tree and adjust accordingly:
[KiTTY left tree with options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggQvs.png)